# Codeigniter trans_start() not rolling back all queries

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, commit, rollback

I have 3 insert queries running between trans_start() and trans_complete(). They are running perfectly fine... The only problem is, when I run rollback before complete it only rollback insert query 1 and 3. These are the only queries rolling back even I tried to change its positions and no success. Please let me know what I am doing wrong? I tried writing queries by $this->db->query(...) instead of using active records but its giving same result...

I have the following code.

```
            $this->db->trans_start();

            //insert transaction

                $i_data = array(
                      'user_id'     => $app['opp_id']
                    , 'amount'      => $app['total']
                    , 'type'        => 1
                    , 'feb_bal'     => 1
                    , 'note'        => 'Earnings' 
                );

                $this->db->insert('transaction', $i_data);
                $tran_id = $this->db->insert_id();

            //insert 2
                $c_data = array(
                      'oppt_opp_id' => $app['id']
                    , 'status'      => 0 //closed
                );
                $this->db->insert('progress', $c_data);


            //insert 3 

                $e_data = array(
                      'tran_id' => $tran_id
                    , 'app_id'  => $app['id']
                    , 'type'    => 1
                    , 'status'  => 2
                );
                $this->db->insert('earn_spend', $e_data);


             $this->db->trans_rollback();

            $this->db->trans_complete();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> CodeIgniter's database abstraction allows you to use transactions with
>   databases that support transaction-safe table types. In MySQL, you'll
>   need to be running InnoDB or BDB table types rather than the more
>   common MyISAM.

**Documentation:** http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html

And could you try following codes? I prepared codes according to the CI document

```
<?php

$this->db->trans_begin();

//insert transaction
$i_data = array(
      'user_id'     => $app['opp_id']
    , 'amount'      => $app['total']
    , 'type'        => 1
    , 'feb_bal'     => 1
    , 'note'        => 'Earnings' 
);

$this->db->insert('transaction', $i_data);
$tran_id = $this->db->insert_id();

//insert 2
$c_data = array(
      'oppt_opp_id' => $app['id']
    , 'status'      => 0 //closed
);
$this->db->insert('progress', $c_data);

//insert 3 
$e_data = array(
      'tran_id' => $tran_id
    , 'app_id'  => $app['id']
    , 'type'    => 1
    , 'status'  => 2
);
$this->db->insert('earn_spend', $e_data);

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
    $this->db->trans_commit();
}

?>
```

Comment: Already tried this one, it gives the same result. It doesn't rollback query 2 that is 'progress'...

Comment: @SyedSajid CodeIgniter's database abstraction allows you to use transactions with databases that support transaction-safe table types. In MySQL, you'll need to be running InnoDB or BDB table types rather than the more common MyISAM.

Comment: Wow you are a star... It works like a charm... My table 'progress' type was MyISAM. Can you please add it to your answer and I will choose it as the correct answer please?

Comment: @Bora tried it but didn't worked I also used a switch case. and how do you return query for mysqli_error($result);?

Comment: @treblaluch Did you check out docs? http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html

Comment: @Bora yeah i checked it. Can u check my code please?

Comment: where should i share it with u?